# Finding the right parametrization for a surface integral of the surface $\Sigma = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : z = 2-(x^2+y^2) , 0 \leq z \leq 2 \}$

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

I am asked to evaluate the following integral:

$$ \iint_\Sigma(x^2+y^2)dS$$
where $\Sigma = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : z = 2-(x^2+y^2) ,\, 0 \leq z \leq 2 \}$

To this end, I tried to use the parametrization $\phi_{u,v} = \begin{align} \begin{bmatrix} u\cos(v) \\ u\sin(v) \\ u \end{bmatrix} \end{align} $ with $u \in [0,\sqrt2], v  \in [0,2\pi]$

The norm of the cross product is $\left\lVert\phi_u \times \phi_v\right\rVert = \sqrt2 u$.

I then get that the integral is equal to:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt2} u^2\sqrt2u \ du \ dv = 2\sqrt2\pi$$

However I am unsure, if this parametrization is valid, especially concerning the choice of $ v\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: I can't understand why in the last row of $\phi_{u,v}$ there is $u$; shouldn't it be $1-u^2$?

Comment: The parametrization is not correct. If $u=0$, then $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$, which is not a point of the surface.

Comment: @P.S.Dester yes, as the other commenter pointed out, the parametrization should probably have $2-u^2$ as third component.